# Crosshair as standard mouse pointer. But how?

Tags: mouse, cursor

All I want is to change the default mouse cursor (the upward pointing arrow) into a crosshair. I don't need instructions on how to download a cursor **theme**, I just want a crosshair as the standard pointer. That's all. But I can't get it done. Can't find a theme with a crosshair as default cursor, either. I do have a Windows *.cur* file with the perfect crosshair pointer. Can that be imported, perhaps? Whatever is possible to get me that crosshair, please provide extensive instructions because I'm new to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://gursormaker.sourceforge.net/ allows for importing and creating of X11 cursors. Probably .curs too.

Comment: Yes, well, I downloaded and installed Gursormaker a while ago and it's nowhere to be found. Doesn't show up in the dash, can't find it with the Application Finder or Quick Launch, nothing. But can't I edit a script (or config file) that just switches the pointer to a crosshair cursor instead of an arrow? You know, something like "default_pointer=crosshair.png" ?